# Laravel array validation in Form Request

Tags: php, laravel

I can't validate a field, which contains array elements, in Form Request class.
Rules method:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        "state" => 'required',
        "state.0" => 'required',
        "state.*" => 'required',
    ];
}
```

There is an array in request->all()

```
"state" => array:1 [
  0 => ""
]
```

Zero element is empty. But validation is successful.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's empty but it exists. What happens if you add `"state.0" => 'required|min:1'`?

Comment: Are you calling the rules into your controller and outputting an error message if it fails to pass?

Comment: @Mjh, required should be more than enough to not allow an empty field to pass through.

Comment: What version of laravel is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to handle the **dynamic fields**, you will need to loop through all the posted `"items"` and add a **rule** for **each**.
Here is an updated method demonstrating this:

```
public function rules() {
    $rules = [
          'state' => 'required',
         ];
    foreach($this->request->get('state') as $key => $val) {
        $rules['state.'.$key] = 'required';
    }
    return $rules;
}
```