# Validating Arrays?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've seen how to validate arrays in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#validating-arrays). Using something like:

```
class UsersRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        'users.*.name' => 'required',

    }
}
```

On my form I have the field named:

```
<input name="users[0][name]">
```

This is actually looped out, but have statically added it in above example.

The issue I have is that the above will validate, so if there is no value in the field, it will error, and with a value, it will pass, unfortunately the input does not have an error class on it, as I suspect the name in the error bag is different to the name on the input.

How can I correctly validate / correctly name array inputs in laravel?

Edit.

This is not a duplicate, have tried other answer on SO and they do not work.

Comment: If you dump out the `$request->input()` what are the key names of your input?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate array in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258185/how-to-validate-array-in-laravel)

Comment: "users" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "name" => "sdfa"
      "date" => "sadf"
    ]
  ]

Comment: Can you share the code you use to validate, rather than just the rule?

Comment: It's just a form request. nothing to show.

Comment: I'm trying to help you mate, can you edit your question to add the code when you do your validation please. Are you doing $request->validate(), are you making a validator??? Are any of the values unique? There can be multiple reasons.

Comment: Please explain why this is not a duplicate and show us more details, as posted is equal to any other question on array validation.

Comment: No im not making a validator, im using a form request.

Comment: Please can you just post your code, it's not difficult. No code, no help. simple.

Comment: [Here is what I have found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45217748/laravel-array-validation-in-form-request)

Comment: Outdated question and answer, array validation have changed in laravel since then.

Comment: Then follow the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#validating-arrays) and adapt it, or just make a validator. The documentation wouldn't show it if it doesn't work.

Comment: I think the issue is that the documentation doesnt show how to name your fields correctly

Answer (score 1):

I usually do like this. It's very simple:

```
<input id="users.0.name" name="users[0][name]">
```

Edit:
Correction is it's not required to set an Id attribute until you need them yours is fine:

```
 <input name="users[0][name]">
```

Comment: in error bag the name should be like "users.0.name" which is not friendly to view though, you can write custom message at lang specific for them

Comment: that is annoying as my inputs check errors based on their name

Comment: @panthro I have written custom messages to view friendly messages. But it's obvious by design they will call through those pattern name until you override that pattern